# How to get this parent value?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get a value thanks to parents method of jQuery, but I can't find the good "way".

Can you help me please ?

The event is on the click of .user-create class, and the value to get is "09h00"

```
<li>
   <div class="docheure">
      <span class="heure">
         09h00 <!--IT'S THE VALUE I NEED -->
      </span>
      <span class="doc">
         Dr.Grey
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="detailrdv">
      <p><span>M / Mme</span> : blabla | <span>Phone</span>: 00000</p>
      <p><span>Examen</span> : crane | <span>Secrétaire</span> : M.J</p>
      <p><span>Remarque :</span></p>
      <p>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div style="display: none;" class="commandes">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <!--THIS IS THE LINK EVENT-->
            <a href="#" class="create-user">
               <img src="btn_dupliquer.png" alt="Dupliquer">
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('div').prevAll(':last').children('.heure').text();
```

- the [`closest()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the first ancestor `<div>`
- the [`prevall()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) method to get all previous elements
- the [`last-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) to get the last item from the `.prevAll()` set
- the [`children()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method to target the children of the selected element with the class `heure`
- the [`text()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get its text content

Comment: @Raynos: The `.closest()` method only returns one match (if found). You could use `.parents()` as well, but you'd probably want to couple it with a `:first` selector in case there are additional `div` ancestors. `.parents('div:first')` would be just about equivalent. The other difference is that `.closest()` considers the originating element, but `.parents()` doesn't. Doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: @patrickdw That makes sense, thank you. Always thought closest does some kind `nearby` search in breadth and depth rather then just in depth.

Comment: @Raynos: I think that's a common assumption. I think "closest" is a really poor name for the method. Does very little to describe what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have multiple of this list elements (and therefore need to access the value from a relative position), this could do it (in the click event handler):

```
$(this).closest('div').siblings('.docheure').children('.heure').text();
```

Reference: [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
$("li div.docheure span.heure").text();
```

Comment: This i think wouldn't work since he wants something that can do the same for other <li> elements aswell and this would get all of them.